# Decrypting arbitrary numbers with RSA

Tags: rsa, key-exchange

I want to construct a hash-chain where I want to share millions of small AES-128 keys with Bob over a period of time. Bob should not be able to predict the future keys if he knows the past keys. I also want to avoid having Bob storing all these keys, but rather be able to derive them so that if they know the key from time $t$, they should be able to derive the keys from time $t-1, t-2$, and so on. So, future-to-past derivation should be possible. Past-to-future derivation should be hard.

The hash-chain way of doing this is to start with a random string, hash it with sha256, say, 1 million times, and start the chain with the 1 millionth hash. This way, if Bob is at the 10th iteration of our protocol, and wants to go back to the 6th iteration, he hashes the 10th iteration key 4 times to get the 6th key.

I am wondering if we can do the same with some encryption scheme like RSA. I give Bob my RSA public key $([e, n])$. I start the chain with a large random number in the range $(2, n-1)$, and decrypt it. I am assuming that every number in this range has a valid decryption. This decryption chain can continue as many times. If Bob wants to reconstruct keys, he uses the encryption algorithm, for which he has the public key. I can use some KDF to derive the AES-128 key from this large RSA "number".

Is the RSA-chain scheme as safe as the SHA-chain scheme?

Comment: Seems like "Related questions" from stackexchange works great. I got what I was looking for here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1793/is-rsa-of-a-random-nonce-with-no-padding-safe

Comment: [This question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70998/asymmetric-csprng-where-the-public-key-only-works-backward) also feels closely related.

Comment: Seekable sequential key generators (SSKG), used in reverse order (start from a very high counter value, give them one key at a time counting backwards in the SSKG output, and when given any one key they can recreate all past keys / later SSKG values). https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/397

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposed system seems to be as follows:

- At generation, Alice selects odd $e>2$ and random large primes $p$ and $q$ with $\gcd(p-1,e)=1=\gcd(q-1,e)$; computes $n\gets p\,q$; chooses random $s_0$ in $[1,n)$; and publishes $(n,e,s_0)$. She computes and keeps secret $\lambda(n)\gets(p-1)(q-1)/\gcd(p-1,q-1)$ and $d\gets e^{-1}\bmod\lambda(n)$.
- For successive times $t\in\Bbb N^*$, Alice computes $s_t\gets{s_{t-1}}^d\bmod n$ and publishes $s_t$ at time $t$.
- For $t\in\Bbb N^*$, anyone with knowledge of $(n,e,s_{t-1})$, e.g. Bob, can check an alleged $s_t$, by verifying that $0<s_t<n$ and ${s_t}^e\bmod n=s_{t-1}$. Alternatively, $s_t$ can be verified from $(n,e,s_0)$ by verifying that $0<s_t<n$ and ${s_t}^{(e^t)}\bmod n=s_0$.
- By convention, $k_t=H(s_t)$ where $H$ is some 128-bit PRF, e.g. the low-order 128 bits of SHA-256.

Anyone with knowledge and trust of $(n,e,s_0)$ and knowledge of $s_{t'}$, e.g. Bob, can compute and trust $k_t$ for $0\le t\le t'$.
The intention is that it would be infeasible to derive $k_t$ for $t>t'$. That holds, with some degree of reduction to the RSA problem. Some arguments:

- Given how it is generated, it is overwhelmingly likely that $s_0$ is coprime to both $p$ and $q$. Assuming that, it follows that for fixed $t$, each $s_t$ is uniformly random in $\Bbb Z_n^*$.
- Knowledge of $s_{t'}$ subsumes knowledge of earlier $s_i$ with $i<t'$.
- Finding $s_t$ from $s_{t'}$ for $t>t'$ is solving the RSA problem for public exponent $e^{t-t'}$, or equivalently public exponent $e^{t-t'}\bmod\lambda(n)$, which itself takes quite random-like values in $\Bbb Z_{\lambda(n)}^*$.

Comment: Wait... I tried following your insecurity argument with $t=1 > t'=0$ (i.e. Alice only publishes $n$, $e$ and $s_0$, Bob wants to compute $s_1 = s_0^d \bmod n$), but it seems to me that Bob being able to compute $s_1$ in that case would be directly equivalent to breaking RSA. Now I'm confused. :/

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen: You are of course totally right. Fixed now. Somewhat I wrote ${s_t}^{(t\,e)}\bmod n=s_0$ when really ${s_t}^{(e^t)}\bmod n=s_0$. Oups.

Comment: Ah, a typo. That happens. :) Anyway, thinking about this a bit more, it seems like a reduction _should_ be possible. Basically, if Alice knew that Bob could break this scheme by predicting $s_{t+1}=s_t^d$ when given $(n,e,s_0,\dots,s_t)$, then she could use Bob as an oracle to break RSA encryption by taking a ciphertext $c$ encrypted with the public key $(n,e)$, generating $(s_t, s_{t-1}, s_{t-2}, \dots, s_0) = (c, c^e, c^{e^2}, \dots, c^{e^t})$ and sending those (along with $n$ and $e$) to Bob.

Comment: See my other comment, SSKG:s are relevant https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/397

Comment: @fgrieu I saw your earlier comment and was about to remark on the typo, but then your answer disappeared :-). Now, it's back again, and seems like everything is ok.